# Simple Typing game (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

I am trying to create a typing game that allows users to input the correct alphabets for the word displayed on the screen. If any wrong alphabet is used as input the game won't show a new word until all the alphabets are correctly provided as input. What I am not able to figure out is how I do match multiple characters with Array elements. Here is my code sample.

```js
var p = document.getElementById('word');
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyboardEventsHandle , false);
var wordsList = ['america','japan','italy','jordan','turkey'];
  
function keyboardEventsHandle(e){
    p.append(e.key);

    if(e.key=='a')
    {
        alert('You typed A');
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Typing Tutor</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="word"></p>
        <h3> america </h3>
        <script src="javas.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var p = document.getElementById('word');
var word = document.getElementById("toType")
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyboardEventsHandle , false);
var wordsList = ['america','japan','italy','jordan','turkey'];
var gameRunning = true

var charIndex = 0;
var wordIndex = 0;

function keyboardEventsHandle(e){
  // If you use append here. Every character gets printed out
  // p.append(e.key);
  if(e.key==wordsList[wordIndex].charAt(charIndex) && gameRunning)
    {
        // If you use append here only correct characters get printed out
        p.append(e.key)
        alert('Correct!');
        if (wordsList[wordIndex].length == charIndex + 1) {
          // Defines which word should get controlled
          if (wordsList.length == wordIndex + 1) {
            gameRunning = false;
            alert('Done');
          } else {
            wordIndex++;
            charIndex = 0;
            word.innerHTML = wordsList[wordIndex];
            p.innerHTML = "";
          }
          
        } else {
          // Defines which character of the word should get controlled
          charIndex++;
        }
    }
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Simple Typing Tutor</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="word"></p>
    <h3 id="toType"> america </h3>
  <script src="javas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but there are 2 problems with this code 
1) It is not updating the word(country name) after entering America
2) It is allowing unnecessary elements on the screen. (How to block them?)

Comment: 1) On my side it is changing the word after I typed it in (Just try it again)
2) If you only want, that characters get displayed that are correct, you must move the `p.append(e.key);` down in the if verification for the correct key but I edit my answer for you with that option

Comment: Understood. Indeed it is working now exactly as I needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of elements to match and then do something like this:

```js
const wordsList = ['america','japan','italy','jordan','turkey'];
const listToMatch = ['america','japan'];

let trueOrFalse = listToMatch.every(i=> wordsList.includes(i));
 console.log(trueOrFalse) //true

var anotherList = ['america', 'India'];
trueOrFalse = anotherList.every(i=> wordsList.includes(i));
console.log(trueOrFalse) //false
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but still I'm not clear on that part that how would I get a text from a document that users enter and put that text to an array and then match it with the correct words.  Just like in my code I got text by .key=='a'.

Comment: If there's a text box you're using you can create `onchange` event and when the user finishes typing in the work and click outside of the textbox, the word will get added to your `listToMatch` if I understand correctly.